# Помогите перевести мою задачу на стримы JAVA8 JAVA9

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Учу сейчас стримы из Java 8 и JAVA 9. Проблема такая, как вначале пропустить строки файла после позиции **END OF HEADER**(предпоследняя строка файла), а затем считать каждое значение(оставшиеся цифры) и возможно ли мою задачу сделать на стримах?.

```
2.10           N: GPS NAV DATA                         RINEX VERSION / TYPE
teqc  2017Feb10     UNAVCO Archive Ops  20170418 19:33:16UTCPGM / RUN BY / DATE
    9.2160D+04 -1.1469D+05 -1.3107D+05  7.2090D+05          ION BETA
    9.313225746155D-10 3.552713678801D-15   233472     1930 DELTA-UTC: A0,A1,T,W
                                                            END OF HEADER
29 17  1  1  2  0  0.0 6.356909871101D-04-2.046363078989D-12 0.000000000000D+00
```

Начал делать так:

```
try {
       Files.lines(Paths.get("src/main/java/ab010010.17n"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).// дальше что применять и множества методов?;
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: может вначале попробовать написать без stream'ов?

Comment: если так, то нет смысла дальше использовать стримы.

Comment: может что-нибудь типа [`.reduce((a, b) -> b).orElse(null)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27547525/5812238)[`.split(' ')`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

Comment: а что эта функция даст?)

Comment: я так понимаю будет браться каждая вторая строка и разбиваться на части ( по пробелу)?

Comment: массив «чисел» из последней строчки файла. С помощью `reduce` и `orElse` из всего потока остаётся только последний элемент (то есть последняя строка файла), а затем эта строка разбивается по пробелу. Формат «чисел» очень странный, поэтому что с ними делать дальше я не знаю

Comment: Нужна именно Java8? Девятка не пойдёт?

Comment: пойдет) только 9 что там нового?) приватный  метод интерфейса и все)

Comment: Оооо, там не только приватные методы интерфейса. В 9-ке много новых плюшек!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В Java9 появился метод потока `dropWhile`, серьёзно облегчающий вашу задачу:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("src/main/java/ab010010.17n"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    .dropWhile(s -> !s.contains("END OF HEADER"))
    .skip(1)
    .map(s -> s.split(" "))
    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
    .filter(i -> !i.isEmpty())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: то есть dropWhile это цикл пока не будет в теле false мы не выйдем из него? )

Comment: спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 4):

Как уже было сказано, можно решить задачу с использованием `dropWhile` из Java 9, но можно и написать собственный метод в Java 8, который выполнит аналогичные действия, например, следующим образом:

```
<T> Stream<T> dropWhile(Stream<T> source, Predicate<T> predicate) {
    Spliterator<T> sourceSpliterator = source.spliterator();
    return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T>(
        sourceSpliterator.estimateSize(),
        sourceSpliterator.characteristics()
    ) {
        boolean dropped;

        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
            if (dropped) {
                return sourceSpliterator.tryAdvance(action);
            }
            while (!dropped) {
                if (!sourceSpliterator.tryAdvance(t -> dropped = predicate.test(t))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }, source.isParallel());
}
```

И затем использовать данный метод в своём коде:

```
Stream<String> input = ...
dropWhile(input, s -> s.contains("END OF HEADER"))
    .map(s -> s.split("\\s+"))
    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```